# Passing variable to .blade.php by return on Controller

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to pass a varible from the Controller to my .blade.php file.
I'm returning the view and compacted variables to the .blade.php but it doens't recognize the
variable.
This is the code of the Controller.

```
$contents = Storage::get($request->file('csv_file_1')->store('temporaryfiles'));
$contents2 = Storage::get($request->file('csv_file_2')->store('temporaryfiles'));

return view('comparison.comparison')->with(compact('contents'),$contents)->with(compact('contents2'),$contents2);
```

And i'm trying every way just to get an result but instead i'm getting the "Undefined variable $contents" page. The last method i used was a simple

```
<p>{{$contents}}</p>
```

I don't think it's correct but i don't really remember how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In controller return like:

```
return view('comparison.comparison', compact(['contents', 'contents2']);
```

And make sure your file is in `resources/views/comparison/comparison.blade.php`

Comment: Still says the same unfortunately

Comment: Try to return any random string from your controller and see if it is working

Comment: Yea didn't work i created $handle="Hello world!" on controller and returned it the way u answered my question, then on .blade.php i wrote <p>{{ $handle }}</p>

Comment: Is your blade.php file is inside `resources/views/comparison/comparison.blade.php` (case sensitive)?

Comment: It is i found what was missing... i completly forgot to add php and endphp the thing is that i was trying on foreach and wasn't working to because  the way i want is with foreach...

Comment: If you are in blade component you don't need php tag. Curly brackets `{{}}` stand for it. Pretty sure there is another issue that needs debug.

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$contents = Storage::get($request->file('csv_file_1')->store('temporaryfiles'));
$contents2 = Storage::get($request->file('csv_file_2')->store('temporaryfiles'));

 return view('comparison.comparison', compact('contents','contents2'));
```

if you have defined a veriable above just use tha name inside compact as above and it can be acced inside blade as `<p>{{$contents}}</p>`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables like that it's not mandatory to use compact.

```
return view('comparison.comparison', [
    'contents' => $contents,
    'contents2' => $contents2
]);
```

or if you want with compact:

```
return view('comparison.comparison')->with(compact('contents', 'contents1'));
```